# Client-side React Router: Unable to deep link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been running React apps on Apache with the different apps stored in their respective subdirectories (*i.e. App1 => company.com/app1*). The apps have been running with no issue, but I want to make the leap into React Router.

However, after copying the [basic template](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) and [solving the initial deep linking issue](https://stanko.github.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/) due to the template being hosted in a subdirectory, I find that the surface-level direct linking can render the page fine (i.e. company.com/template/topics) but going any deeper than that (i.e. company.com/template/topics/rendering) and an empty page loads and the following error message is prompted on console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://www.company.com/template/topics/rendering/main.js : Unexpected token (1:1)
 1 | <!DOCTYPE html>
   |  ^
 2 | <html>
 3 |     <head>
 4 |         <meta charset="UTF-8">
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.min.js:41)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.min.js:42)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseIdentifier (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseNamespacedName (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementName (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseOpeningElementAt (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElement (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.min.js:40)
```

My scripts are as follows:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@4.2.0/umd/react-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.2.2/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type='text/babel' src='main.js'></script>
</body>
```

***main.js***

```
// required for ReactRouter V4
console.log(window.ReactRouterDOM)
const BrowserRouter = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter
const Route = window.ReactRouterDOM.Route
const Link = window.ReactRouterDOM.Link
const NavLink = window.ReactRouterDOM.NavLink
const Prompt = window.ReactRouterDOM.Prompt
const Switch = window.ReactRouterDOM.Switch
const Redirect = window.ReactRouterDOM.Redirect

const BasicExample = () => (
    <BrowserRouter basename='/template'>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )

  const Home = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  )

  const About = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  )

  const Topics = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
      <Route
        exact
        path={match.url}
        render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
      />
    </div>
  )

  const Topic = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
      <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  )

ReactDOM.render(<BasicExample/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

***.htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Fallback all other routes to index.html
RewriteRule ^ /template/index.html [L]
```

I am not quite sure how else to modify the Router template such that users can direct link to the appropriate page. Can anybody here kindly advise a solution to this?

Many thanks!

Comment: In your `.htaccess`,  remove the `/template from the `RewriteRule` on the last line. Then add `RewriteBase /template/`

Comment: @RuChernChong Does not work. Same result as in the original question.

Comment: For the time being, I am using the HashRouter module instead of the BrowserRouter. The HashRouter works as intended.